# querying datatable using linq and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I have looked at many sites and am not able to understand how I would go about using linq to query the first couple of rows of a data-table.

I would also like to know with regards to this if the data came from an Excel file would the column references be the same? For example column F in would be the same in the datatable or a numbered reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DataTable yourDataTable = new DataTable();
var result = yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Take(2) // Select first two rows
    .Select(r =>
        new
        {
            Field1 = r.Field<int>("col1"), // Select your columns
            Field2 = r.Field<string>("col2")
            // your rest of the columns
        }
    );
```

If you want to select only the second row then:

```
var result = yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Skip(1) // skip first row
    .Take(1) // Select second row
    .Select(r =>
        new
        {
            Field1 = r.Field<int>("col1"), // Select your columns
            Field2 = r.Field<string>("col2")
            // your rest of the columns
        }
    );
```

**EDIT:**

To Select all columns, instead of specific one, just remove the `Select` from the statement. Something like this:

```
var result = yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Skip(1)  // skip first row
    .Take(1); // Select second row
```

Comment: will it take the whole of the second row

Comment: @user1776590, this will take the first two Rows. Do you want to select only the second row ?

Comment: so i would have to select each of the columns indervidually not together

Comment: @user1776590 just remove `Select` operator - it will give you rows.

Comment: @user1776590, then remove the `Select` and you will get all the columns

Comment: but is there any way off selecting all of the columns at once instead of indervidually

Comment: @user1776590, you are welcome, if you think this solves your issue then remember to accept it as an answer

Comment: the system didnt let me at the time and so i did it now

Comment: one more quick question would i be able to select data based on a string in a row

Comment: @user1776590, you can use where clause, something like, `yourtable.AsEnumberable().Where(r=> r.Field<string>("Col1").Equals("yourstring"));`