# Querying a datatable with top clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, datatable

I am implementing paging in my datalist. (visual studio 2008)

For that i have datatable on which i want to make query for paging.

I have following datatable:

[image]

I wanted to implement following SQLquery:

```
select top 5 * from (select   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Index) as Row from users) T where Row > " 10
```

I want to make same query on this datatable as above.

I was confused how to use "top" to query datatable.

For that i made following attempt:

```
DTResult.Select("Index < " & Integer.Parse(ddlPage.SelectedValue.ToString()))
```

(note: `ddlPage` is my dropdown containing numbers for paging like 5,10,25,etc)

This attempt is not giving me intended result.

please help me.

Comment: try skip and take in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Linq to get SQL like operations in C#

```
DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();// Yur Table here
  var FirstResult = from Row in MyTable.AsEnumerable()
                    orderby Row.Field<int>("Index")
                    select new
                    {
                      KioskId = Row.Field<string>("KioskId"),
                      Index = Row.Field<int>("Index"),
                      FileName = Row.Field<string>("FileName")
                    };
  var AfterRowNumbering = FirstResult.Select((x, index) => new  {
                      KioskId=x.KioskId,
                      Index=x.Index,
                      FileName = x.FileName,
                      Row_Number = index
                      }).Take(5);
 var FinalResult = from row in AfterRowNumbering
                   where row.Row_Number > 10
                   select row;
```

This expressions can be further simplified.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use LINQ Query to find out your desired output.

I think this link will give you answer

[querying datatable using linq and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360113/querying-datatable-using-linq-and-c-sharp)

Comment: .Take(2) after Enumerable is not comming

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code it will give you your desired output.

```
DataView dv = new DataView(DTResult);
dv.RowFilter = "ID < " + ddlPage.SelectedValue.ToString();
DTResult = dv.ToTable();
```

After this you will directly give "DTResult" data table to your datalist.

Comment: i want to implement top clause on it as i mentioned in sql query, how can i do that?